# Will backbonejs model cid be unique across multiple collection?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I want to know that will backbone model cid will unique among multiple collection.
Example: I have pageCollection and each pageCollection will contains another collection called controlCollection.

If I am creating control model, its cid will be unique among all controlCollection inside all pageCollection?

hierarchy:

```
pageCollection
  ->pageModel
    ->controlCollection
      ->controlModel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering same model can be present inside multiple collections by design in backbone, it'll be unique. No other model will have same `cid`.

Comment: Thanks @T J.... I am somehow getting duplicate cid in above architecture with controlModel model.. I don't know how to find it out as it happening very rarely.

Comment: Are you sure it's totally different model instances? what version of underscore/backbone are you using? Maybe an old version with some bug?

Comment: hmm... Yes. I hope the same.. I am using Backbone.js 1.1.2 with  Underscore.js 1.5.2.